# Thought godmother wasn’t related, but she’s a MATCH?

Tags: autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

Close Family – 1st Cousin
24% sharedd DNA: 1,677 cM across 42 segments.

I was always under the impression that my godmother was not my relative, but, much to my surprise, the above results came back in my (Ancestry) DNA test.
There’s a bit more to the story. My godfather happens to be her father.
My godmother’s mother, godfather’s wife, passed away when she was a young girl and was raised by my godfather. I have tried to figure out every scenario where this could be possible and the only thing that might make sense is that (ugh) my godfather might actually be my father. I really hope this is not true.
My relatives are from the the Greek islands, and I have been told that this can possibly create false matches. At least I hope so. But the bad news is that my mom and dad split up when I was a young kid. And, We all know that families do keep secrets.
Can anybody tell me if there is any possible way that my godmother is simply a cousin and how that would actually be the case?
My mom and dad only had one sibling each. My dad’s brother never had children.
Oh, and I am apparently named after my godfather’s deceased wife.

Comment: [DNA Painter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1677) says that 1677 cM is not a cousin. However, that comes with a caveat: "Assuming no pedigree collapse or endogamy"

Answer (score 3):

DNA painter puts 1677 cM at 100% probability of the following for your godmother’s relationship to you:  Grandparent/Aunt or Uncle/Niece or Nephew/Half-sibling/Grandchild.

Your godmother is extremely unlikely to be a cousin.

It would seem that your godmother as your Grandparent and your godmother as your Grandchild can be ruled out based on the information provided.

Your godmother as an Aunt or Uncle would mean that your godmother is a (unknown or unacknowledged) sibling of your mother or your father.  This seems quite unlikely based on the information provided.

Your godmother would be a niece/nephew if either your godfather or his wife is a (full) sibling of your father or your mother (again perhaps unknown or unacknowledged).  Ages and/or relative birth years and death ages (if dead) of grandparents, mother/father, godfather/wife, godmother might help pin down the likelihood.

Your godmother would be a half-sibling if your father is also her father with your godfather’s wife as her (biologic) mother.

Another half-sibling scenario is that your godfather is your (biologic) father and your (biologic) mother is your godmother's mother.

That is about as far as one can go with just the stated DNA results.